# While displaying objects in IndexedDB getting an issue in service worker

Tags: javascript, web-applications, indexeddb, service-worker, offline-storage

Right now getting an issue in displaying a IndexedDB objects. please some one help to do the progress in the same. in my case,once if i enable the offline image will display from dynamic cache but indexedDB looks empty objects. so that help me to display the image from the IndexedDB.here below is the code i have tried:

```
  function createCard(data)
  {
     var asd = data;
     $.each(asd, function(index, data) {
     var template='<a href="viewexpense1.html class="expenseItem">\n\
    <div class="itemReceipt">\n\
    <img src="'+data.image+'">\n\
    <span class="itemCategory"><img src="images/meals.png"></span>\n\
    </div>\n\
    <div class="expenseName singleLine">\n\
    <h3>'+data.tittle+'<img src="images/sync.png"></h3>\n\
    </div>\n\
     <div class="clearfix"> </div>\n\
    </a>';
    $('#reportContent').append(template);
  });                       
  } 

    var url='https://pwa-cssi.firebaseio.com/ posts.json';
    var networkDataReceived = false;
    fetch(url)
       .then(function(res)
        { 
                return res.json();
         })
        .then(function(data)
        {
             networkDataReceived =true;
             console.log('from web',data);
             var dataArray=[];
             for(var key in data)
             {
                   dataArray.push(data[key]);
             }
             console.log(data)
             createCard(dataArray); 
         });
         if('caches' in window)
           {
               caches.match(url)
               .then(function(response)
                {
                        if(response)
                        {
                           return response.json();
                        }
                })
                .then(function(data)
                {
                     console.log('From cache',data);
                     if(!networkDataReceived)
                     {
                        var dataArray=[];
                        for(var key in data)
                        {
                            dataArray.push(data[key]);
                        }
                        createCard(dataArray)
                      }
                })
           }

        if('indexedDB' in window)
        {
              console.log('123');
              readAllData('posts')
              .then(function(data){
              console.log('456');
              if(!networkDataReceived)
              {
                    console.log('From cache s',data);
                     var dataArray=[];
                    createCard(dataArray);
                  });
                }
```

and i have code like this for read allData function

```
      function readAllData(posts)
       {
           console.log('asdasdasd');
           return dbPromise
                   .then (function(db){
                       var tx=db.transaction('posts','readonly');
                 var store=tx.objectStore('posts');
                 console.log('asdasdasd123');
                 return store.getAll();

           });
       }
  please some one help me.i got struck for since last 2 days
```

Comment: Please some one help me.i am unable to figure out.

Comment: Hi! I would like to help you but I don't understand your question. You have to provide a cleaner question so people can help you. What do you mean by empty objects? What do you mean by displaying? Try to enhance your original question :)

Comment: I am trying to display image from backend firebase console,I added that image to IndexedDB.While retrieving the image from the IndexedDB in offline mode it is not displaying.